# Low Level Keyboard Hook Lockscreen C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook

I am using this code from github to create and use a low level keyboard hook:

```
 class GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs : HandledEventArgs {
        public GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState KeyboardState { get; private set; }
        public GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent KeyboardData { get; private set; }

        public GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(
            GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent keyboardData,
            GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState keyboardState) {
            KeyboardData = keyboardData;
            KeyboardState = keyboardState;
        }
    }

    //Based on https://gist.github.com/Stasonix
    class GlobalKeyboardHook : IDisposable {
        public event EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> KeyboardPressed;

        public GlobalKeyboardHook() {
            _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _hookProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc; // we must keep alive _hookProc, because GC is not aware about SetWindowsHookEx behaviour.

            _user32LibraryHandle = LoadLibrary("User32");
            if (_user32LibraryHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to load library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }



            _windowsHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hookProc, _user32LibraryHandle, 0);
            if (_windowsHookHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to adjust keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
            if (disposing) {
                // because we can unhook only in the same thread, not in garbage collector thread
                if (_windowsHookHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
                    if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(_windowsHookHandle)) {
                        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to remove keyboard hooks for '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                    }
                    _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                    // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
                    _hookProc -= LowLevelKeyboardProc;
                }
            }

            if (_user32LibraryHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
                if (!FreeLibrary(_user32LibraryHandle)) // reduces reference to library by 1.
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Failed to unload library 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                }
                _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        ~GlobalKeyboardHook() {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private IntPtr _windowsHookHandle;
        private IntPtr _user32LibraryHandle;
        private HookProc _hookProc;

        delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        /// <summary>
        /// The SetWindowsHookEx function installs an application-defined hook procedure into a hook chain.
        /// You would install a hook procedure to monitor the system for certain types of events. These events are
        /// associated either with a specific thread or with all threads in the same desktop as the calling thread.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">hook type</param>
        /// <param name="lpfn">hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="hMod">handle to application instance</param>
        /// <param name="dwThreadId">thread identifier</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is the handle to the hook procedure.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// The UnhookWindowsHookEx function removes a hook procedure installed in a hook chain by the SetWindowsHookEx function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hhk">handle to hook procedure</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);

        /// <summary>
        /// The CallNextHookEx function passes the hook information to the next hook procedure in the current hook chain.
        /// A hook procedure can call this function either before or after processing the hook information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHook">handle to current hook</param>
        /// <param name="code">hook code passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">value passed to hook procedure</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent {
            /// <summary>
            /// A virtual-key code. The code must be a value in the range 1 to 254.
            /// </summary>
            public int VirtualCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// A hardware scan code for the key. 
            /// </summary>
            public int HardwareScanCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// The extended-key flag, event-injected Flags, context code, and transition-state flag. This member is specified as follows. An application can use the following values to test the keystroke Flags. Testing LLKHF_INJECTED (bit 4) will tell you whether the event was injected. If it was, then testing LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED (bit 1) will tell you whether or not the event was injected from a process running at lower integrity level.
            /// </summary>
            public int Flags;

            /// <summary>
            /// The time stamp stamp for this message, equivalent to what GetMessageTime would return for this message.
            /// </summary>
            public int TimeStamp;

            /// <summary>
            /// Additional information associated with the message. 
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr AdditionalInformation;
        }

        public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        //const int HC_ACTION = 0;

        public enum KeyboardState {
            KeyDown = 0x0100,
            KeyUp = 0x0101,
            StrgKey = 0x00000100,
            SysKeyDown = 0x0104,
            SysKeyUp = 0x0105
        }

        public const int VkSnapshot = 0x2c;
        public const int VkLwin = 0x5b;
        public const int VkRwin = 0x5c;
        public const int VkTab = 0x09;
        public const int VkEscape = 0x18;
        public const int VkControl = 0x11;
        public const int KfAltdown = 0x2000;
        public const int LlkhfAltdown = (KfAltdown >> 8);

        public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
            bool fEatKeyStroke = false;

            var wparamTyped = wParam.ToInt32();
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(KeyboardState), wparamTyped)) {
                object o = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent));
                LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent p = (LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent)o;

                var eventArguments = new GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(p, (KeyboardState)wparamTyped);

                EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> handler = KeyboardPressed;
                handler?.Invoke(this, eventArguments);

                fEatKeyStroke = eventArguments.Handled;
            }

            return fEatKeyStroke ? (IntPtr)1 : CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
```

This code works just fine for capturing ALT+# . Problem is that after I locked my machine the hook does not work anymore. Any advice on how to get it working after unlocking the machine, or on how to stop it from "breaking" in the first place.